# ReduceRegions Graph JavaScript in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to get NDVI values as a featureCollection with my nodejs server. But the "ReduceRegions" function does not recognize the input. How to solve this problem?

EE code link: (where it works fine) https://code.earthengine.google.com/3f8355e66a11f2a4db69d82b350deb90

> Error: Unrecognized argument type to convert to a FeatureCollection: [object Object]
>       at new ee.FeatureCollection (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:16907:17)
>       at Function.ee.promote_ [as promoter_] (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:17822:53)
>       at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.promoteArgs (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15799:40)
>       at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.apply (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15776:49)
>       at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.callOrApply (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15793:15)
>       at ee.Image.destination.(anonymous function).signature.destination.(anonymous function) [as reduceRegions] (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:15945:24)
>       at reduce (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\functions\graphNdvi.js:25:22)
>       at C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:16505:12
>       at new ee.CustomFunction (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:17444:24)
>       at Function.ee.CustomFunction.create (C:\Users\Omen-\Desktop\heroku\ams-ocp\node_modules@google\earthengine\build\main.js:17502:10)

```
var app = function (image) {
        var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']);
        image = image.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'));
        return image;
    };

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
        .filterBounds(inputs.reg)
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
        .filterDate(inputs.date[0], inputs.date[1])
        .map(app);

var reduce = function (image) {
        return image.reduceRegions(
            {
                collection: inputs.reg,
                scale: 30,
                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
            })
}

var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection(collection.select(["NDVI"]))
var featureCollection = ndvi.map(reduce).flatten();
```

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot.

Comment: I added a link to the code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused--I didn't realize you could use the javascript API outside of the online code editor. Why not print the type for ndvi to make sure it's an imagecollection like you expect?

Comment: Google earth engine can be used outside the code editor using a custom application either with nodejs or some python server. This is the link from the documentation showing how to do it : https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro. You can also check the "demos" section in the official github repository: https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/tree/master/demos. I also made a public repository of a website using earth engine Javascript API with NodeJS (EXPRESS) : https://github.Com/omenranr/EEnode-demo

Comment: Ok, cool, good to know. But what happens if you print collection and ndvi?

Comment: If I print it in the online code editor it's effectively an ImageCollection, in my server side it prints the metadata of "ndvi". But apparently in the server side the "ndvi" which is supposed to be an ImageCollection is not recognized by ReduceRegions.

Comment: In the python API I use type() to determine the object type--is there something like that for your API?

Comment: ndvi is indeed an ImageCollection because I can for example get the mapid and token from it to show in the map. But the problem I think is with "ReduceRegions" or the way it's called. https://github.com/Omenranr/EEnode-demo/blob/master/functions/ndvi.js